# Skip tests in Angular project generated with Yo

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, yeoman-generator

I'm doing a small toy project to test Yeoman and angular.

After having created the application with `yo angular` I've started writing a service and its tests. Everything was perfect until I tried to ignore a test.

From what I've read I should be able to ignore a test changing `it` to `xit` and a suit changing `describe` to `xdescribe`.

But when I save and grunt launches the tests, I get a `'xit' is not defined` or `'xdescribe' is not defined` error.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: open `Gruntfile.js` at the end locate `grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);` remove the `test` line, when you need to test use `grunt test`

Comment: After changing what you suggested, it keeps failing, but, anyway, I don't want to disable ´jshint´.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Even after adding `xdescribe` and `xit` to the `.jshintrc` file it still thrown an error. My project is also an `angular-generator` app.

Comment: @mrjedmao Did you modify the `test/.jshintrc`? I ask because there is another `.jshintrc` at the root of the application.

Comment: @Federico Nafria, yes, I did.

Comment: I did exactly what TestersGonnaTest suggested in his answer and its working now. I did not modify the `GruntFile`. @mrjedmao

Comment: @FedericoNafria, well it's working now, so I must have done it wrong the first time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to edit or maybe create a file called .jshintrc, and you will have something like this:

```
{
    "curly": false,
    "eqeqeq": false,
    "immed": true,
    "latedef": true,
    "newcap": true,
    "noarg": true,
    "sub": true,
    "undef": true,
    "boss": true,
    "eqnull": true,
    "browser": true,
    "es5":true,
    "smarttabs": true,
    "expr":true,
    "globals": {
        "angular": true,
        "console": true,
        "expect" : true,
        "inject" : true,
        "describe" : true,
        "beforeEach" : true,
        "it" : true,
        "xit" : true,
        "xdescribe": true
    }
}
```

Notice the xit and xdescribe under globals.

In your gruntfile go to jshint task and have this

```
 
jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
      }
}
```

Comment: Could this be a bug in the app generation?

Comment: I don't really understand your question.
From jshint docs: 
JSHint comes with a default set of warnings but it was designed to be very configurable. There are three main ways to configure your copy of JSHint: you can either specify the configuration file manually via the --config flag, use a special file .jshintrc or put your config into your projects package.json file under the jshintConfig property.

Comment: Yes, I understand that is possible to configure jsHint, but it seems weird that Yeoman is generating the app without the possibility to ignore tests.